# NSArray change type of NSNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to store some NSNumber as double in a NSArray. So I tried that :

```
NSArray *diamArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.0],
                     [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.2],
                     nil];
```

And then, I ask Xcode to show the diamArray:

```
NSLog(@"%@", diamArray);
```

And here is the result:

```
[8873:1153347] (
    1,
    "1.2"
)
```

So we can see that both numbers are not treated the same way. It's a problem for me as these values are usable as their type changes. Specially, in the debug watch of the array, I can see the decimal number (1.2) as "double" but the 1.0 value is shown as "null".

How can I force the array to consider 1.0 as a double ?

Comment: It's just a log. How are you actually using the value in the array where it's a problem?

Answer (score 6):

It can be confusing to decipher data types from NSLog as it is attempting to display convenient information.  In this case, 1.0 is exactly one, so it is truncating that value so that it appears to be an Int.  I'll almost guarantee that if you were to pull the item out of the array and display it's objCType you'd find that it's a double:

```
NSLog("%@: %s", diamArray[0], [diamArray[0] objCType]);
```

The other thing to consider is that values can be cast coming out of NSNumber, so even if it stores 1.0 as an integer value, you can still extract it as a double:

```
[diamArray[0] doubleValue]
```

Answer (score 2):

NSNumber is a **class cluster**. You should not worry about how it store the information, but you should instead mostly care about **how you retrieve** that information.

To get back your **double**, you have just to do:

```
double myDouble = [dimArray[0] doubleValue];
```

but there are also:

```
[dimArray[0] intValue];
[dimArray[0] integerValue];
[dimArray[0] unsignedIntegerValue];
[dimArray[0] floatValue];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your info and suggestions.

I find out that it's related to locale. My default locale is fr_FR and then I tried that:

```
NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
f.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[f setLocale:usLocale];
 NSArray *pasArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     [f numberFromString:[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.0] stringValue]],
                     [f numberFromString:[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.25] stringValue]],
nil];
```

and it works as expected. I guess that, due to locale difference, the dot is misinterpreted. But I think it's not really clean to do so.

My conclusion is that David Berry is right: I don't have to care about the display and rather ask for the format I need when I need it.

Thanks again to help me to understand why it wasn't a problem.